Set atomfamily value in jotai
I'm having trouble trying to set value to my atomfamily in jotai. I get possible unhandeled promise rejection: Error: atom is not writable. I want to set the currentl result to useratom. how do I achieve this?
export const userAtomFamily = atomFamily<string, any>((uid: string) => {
  const userAtom = atom<any, any, any>(
    async () => {
      try {
        const user = await UserController.get(uid);
        // get user and check
        return user;
      } catch (err) {
        return null;
      }
    },
    async (
      get,
      set,
      userData: {uid: string; displayName: string; username: string},
    ) => {
      const localUser = await UserController.createUser({
        uid: userData.uid,
        displayName: userData.displayName,
        username: userData.username,
      });
      await registerUser(userData).catch(async (err: any) => {
        console.log('[registerUser]', err);
        await UserController.deleteUser({uid: userData.uid});
        return;
      });

      set(userAtomFamily(uid), localUser); <---error 
    },
  );
  return userAtom;
});

